# Compare values with bitwise operations

Tags: sql, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Is it possible to use bitwise operations effectively to compare two values where the second value is a superset of the first?

If I have attributes 1, 2 and 3 as ON, I need to match that to a value where attributes 1 and 2 can be ON or OF and 3 must be ON.

```
enum user_attribs {
    attrib1 = 0, attrib2 = 1, attrib3 = 2
}

enum spt_attribs {
    attrib1 = 0, attrib2 = 1, attrib3 = 2
}

user_attribs u1 = attrib1 & attrib2 & attrib3;

spt_attribs s1 = attrib1 & attrib2 | attrib3;
```

Would `u1 = s1` be valid in SQL with the above code?

UPDATE: The RDBMS is SQL SERVER 2008 R2. I'm trying to compare the stored attributes in the database. I'd like to be able to compare to success the value of a "user profile" to a "system profile," where the system profile is a superset of the user's, e.g. the user profile should match the system profile. If the user's bits are set to `1101` it would match the system bit `1101` or `1001` or `1100`, etc. I need the system profile to match on both settings in the "WHERE" clause of the SQL statement.

Comment: what does "compare to success the value" mean?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated your RDBMS, but SQL Server supports bitwise operators:

- [Bitwise Operators (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx)

And you would use like:

```
-- must be powers of 2...
attrib1 = 1
attrib2 = 2
attrib3 = 4
...

-- Check if attrib1 and atrrib2 are set
IF ((col1 & (atrib1 | attrib2)) = (atrib1 | attrib2)
```

Oracle has BitAND:

- [BitAND](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions014.htm)

MySQL has Bit Functions:

- [Bit Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

this is not something that you can do with SQL.  You might be talking about TSQL or PL/SQL.  What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: not really, he asked if he could do it in sql and I answered him

Comment: @jworrin: I think you need to clarify what *you* mean by 'SQL'. TSQL and PL/SQL both implement entry level Standard SQL-92. However, Standard SQL-92 does not provide such operators by design. A similar example is `mod` function/operator: not provided by the Standards but all SQL products have one.